# converting svg files with google fonts into png - PHP

Tags: php, svg, imagick

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" width="100%" version="1.1" height="100%"><defs><style> @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One);</style></defs><text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="text-anchor: middle; ; font-size: 100px;" x="10%" y="32.36134453781513%" text-anchor="middle" font="" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-family="   Faster One   , cursive" font-size="78%" id="text2"><tspan dy="NaN">hii</tspan></text></svg>
```

When i tried to convert this **svg** into **png** using PHP `imagick`, it only renders the text in default font only (arial).

is there any way to use the same google font to render the text, when converting into png ?

Any help would greatly be appreceated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS can render the SVG including Google Fonts with a little work. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10592